# Excel data validation incompatible

Tags: excel

I'm currently working on creating a dropdown list that hides selected items in Excel. I am using Excel 2016 and my file's type is Excel 97-2003 Workbook (xls).
The problem is, when I try to save my file, compatibility checker pops up. It only works on xlsx files. I think my formula for data validation could be the reason why. Any ideas or tips to fix this issue? Please. Thank you very much.

Here are the images
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: The easy and obvious answer is save as `XLSX`. Any reason why you must save as `XLS`?

Comment: Not all clients have the 2007 and up version of Excel. So that all clients can open the file regardless of their Excel version, I need to save as .xls. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@cybernetic.nomad asks a reasonable question: "why not save it in .xlsx format?"

But if you really want to know why the compatibility checker comes up, the reason is this:

List Validation Ranges in Excel 97-2003 cannot refer to a range on another Worksheet (unless they are in a Named Range).

To get it to work with a Named Range:

1. copy your validation formula to the clipboard
2. bring up the Named Range dialogue (Ctrl+F3)
3. add a new Named Range (name=usernames, scope=Workbook, Refers To=[=your validation formula])
4. go back into the Data Validation dialogue where you want the dropdown and change the Source to "=usernames"